# Remainder when dividing $13^{3530}$ with $12348$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the remainder when dividing $13^{3530}$ with $12348$.

How do I solve these type of exercises? I know there's some algorithm for solving them, I just haven't found a concrete example. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to calculate $13^{3530} \mod 12348$. The easiest algorithm for modular exponentiation is the binary exponentiation, more commonly called "square & multiply". You can find plenty of examples online. Speedhack though: You can reduce the exponent modulo $\phi(12348)$ (Euler-Phi, Euler's Theorem). Through factorizing that number you see that $\phi(12348) = 3528$. Reducing the exponent now only leaves $13^{3530-3528} = 13^2 \mod 12348$ to be computed, which is simply $13^2 = 169$.

Comment: Have you tried using Euler's theorem that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$ if $a$ is coprime to $n$? The condition holds, since 13 is no divisor of 12348. Calculating $\phi(12348)$ should make this easy, I think.

Comment: Checkout the previous Questions shown in the Related sidebar on the desktop site.  For example, [How to find reminder of 
$m^x$ divided by $n$ using Euler's and Fermat's little theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502397/how-to-find-reminder-of-mx-divided-by-n-using-eulers-and-fermats-little)

Comment: Any interested party is welcome to weigh in in the discussion in [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23458/11619). In particular whether me closing this as a duplicate of the more generic question was appropriate or not.

Comment: For the record: I closed this as a duplicate of [this generic Q&A](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619). The meta discussion is about whether that was an appropriate thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

As $12348=2^23^27^3,$

$13\equiv1\pmod{2^2}\implies13^n\equiv1\ \ \ \ (1)$

$13^3=(1+12)^3\equiv1\pmod{3^2}$

As $3530\equiv2\pmod3,13^{3530}\equiv13^2\pmod9\equiv7\ \ \ \ (2)$

Now $\phi(7^3)=7^2(7-1)$ and $3530\equiv2\pmod{7^2(7-1)}$
$\implies13^{3530}\equiv13^2\pmod{7^3}\equiv169\ \ \ \ (3)$

Now apply CRT on $(1),(2),(3)$

---

Alternatively, using [Carmichael function,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $$\lambda(2^23^27^3)=294$$ and $$3530\equiv2\pmod{294}$$

$$\implies13^{3530}\equiv13^2\pmod{2^23^27^3}$$

Comment: We seem to think differently about whether this is a duplicate or not. This needs to be a community decision, so may be you should join in the discussion in [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23458/11619). At least if we get a discussion going.

Comment: Anyway, I would welcome it if you compiled an example explaining the use of the Carmichael function as an answer to the [generic thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,  https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Carmichael%20function%20bhattacharjee%20site%3A%2F%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions&rct=j

Comment: @Jyrki: It's worth noting the generic thread does [have an answer about using the Chinese Remainder theorem to separate the problem into its constituent factors.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1819464/14972)